# datetime error on inserting from csv to mysql

Tags: python

I am trying to inserting csv  file to mysql but everything except datetime column is been inserted. I have been struck with this datetime column for 2 hours and it inserts into pay and display but into payload function addWhitelistEntryValue.

this is the error  I receive :

```
File "/usr/local/bin/ringo.py", line 62, in <module>
    (start_date,start_time) = start_datetime.split(" ")
NameError: name 'start_datetime' is not defined
```

this is  my script :

```
try:
    csvfile = sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "Usage %s CSVfile" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

# Login in to get a valid session
curl = pycurl.Curl()
body = Body()

payload = [("username", "screen"), ("passwd", "now")]
try:
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, login_url)
    curl.setopt(curl.COOKIEJAR, cookie_file)
    curl.setopt(curl.HTTPPOST, payload)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, body.gotData)
    curl.perform()
    curl.close()
    print body.contents
except:
    print "Local Curl Failed"
    print "URL: ", insert_url
    print "Payload: ", payload
    print "Result: ", body.contents
    sys.exit(2)

reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile, 'r'))
all(next(reader) for row in range(2)) #skip the headers row

for row in reader:
    print row
    try:
        (location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime,ticket_price,crap) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
    except:
        print "Error with row: " % row
      (start_date,start_time) = start_datetime.split(" ")
      (end_date,end_time) = end_datetime.split(" ")
    vrm = vrm.replace(' ', '')
    vrm = vrm.upper()
    SessionCost = float(ticket_price)/ 100
    entryDatetime = ("%s %s "  % (start_date, start_time)).replace('/','-')
    expiryDatetime = ("%s %s " % (end_date, end_time)).replace('/','-')
    sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
        (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
        VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, "Ringo WL",SessionCost)
    print sql_local
    cursor.execute(sql_local)

    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    body = Body()

    payload = [("fn", "addWhitelistEntryValue"),
        ("startDate", start_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
        ("startTime", ""),
        ("endDate", end_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
        ("endTime", ""),
        ("vrm", vrm.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
        ("locId", location_id.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
        ]
    try:
        curl.setopt(curl.URL, insert_url)
        curl.setopt(curl.COOKIEFILE, cookie_file)
        curl.setopt(curl.HTTPPOST, payload)
        curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, body.gotData)
        curl.perform()
        curl.close()
        print body.contents
    except:
        print "Local Curl Failed"
        print "URL: ", insert_url
        print "Payload: ", payload
        print "Result: ", body.contents
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: It looks like something is going wrong in the `(location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime,ticket_price,crap) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]` line, but you can't see what it is because you have a "naked" except clause. You should always catch a particular exception -- or group of exceptions if you must -- instead.

Comment: I see a indentation issue, does `(start_date,start_time) = start_datetime.split(" ")` goes under the exception block or in the same block ? If it goes under the exception block then the error that you got make sense, did you try with proper indentation ?

Comment: Is the time in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: yes, it is yyyy-mm-dd format and it is not having any indentation issues.